# Why we do we use "have" with singulars?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, phrase-meaning

Why do we use "have" with singulars, I mean we have read the formula that we use "has" with singulars and "have" with plurals, but in some sentences I read "have" with singulars. For example,

1. Does she have a car?
2. She does not have a van?

Why we are using "have" here?

Comment: That **does** takes over and acts as a singular verb instead of **have**.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is basic grammar.  The verb is conjugated according to the subject, not whether the subject is singular or plural.  *I **have** a van*, *you **have** a van*, *she **has** a van*, *they **have** a van*, and so on.  With questions, you conjugate the helping verb "do", and leave the main verb in the infinitive form.  ***Do** I **have** a van?*, ***does** she **have** a van?* and so on.  An English textbook should help you understand this.

Comment: @Andrew We shouldn't close a question just because it asks basic grammar. The OP is genuinely confused and ELL folks are supposed to help them. This is not ELU or Linguistics.SE.

Comment: @user178049  we are not a substitute for an English primer or a basic ESL course.  Verb conjugation is first-year stuff -- if OP doesn't even understand this, then there's more going on than a simple answer can help ameliorate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The auxiliary verb "do"/"does"/"did" must be followed by the plain form of verb.

i. She **has** a car.

ii. *Does* she **have** a car?

ii She *doesn't* **have** a car.